# Vue CSS dependency not found error on Azure deploy

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, build, azure-devops

I have a vue app created largely according to this tutorial but without CRUD functionality: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/05/15/vue-login.

It's created with Vue cli 4.3.1 using vue create.

It runs great with npm run serve, and builds without errors when built locally.

I am now trying to deploy via an azure pipeline to an azure web app. The yaml I am using is below. The yaml starts fine and gets through the npm install. When it gets to devBuild (vue-cli-service lint & vue-cli-service build --mode dev), the deploy fails saying it can't find two dependencies, which appear to be the CSS files for the welcome and home components. Other components in the same directory that have CSS files in the same directory do not have any issues. I have tried doing a "require ("./home.css") at the top instead, and tried alternate path references in both the require or style tag methods, such as:

```
<style scoped>
     @import "./home.css";
</style>
<style scoped>
     @import "@/home.css";
</style>
<style scoped>
     @import "home.css";
</style>
```

None of that seems to make a difference. I cannot figure why these 2 CSS files are creating issues and they are the only ones creating a problem.

---

Error on deploy:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* -!../../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./home.css in ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=8dc7cce2&scoped=true&lang=css&

* -!../../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./welcome.css in ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=d4b7673c&scoped=true&lang=css&
```

---

yaml used for pipeline:

```js
# Node.js with Vue
# Build a Node.js project that uses Vue.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '13.7'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm run devBuild
  displayName: 'npm dev build'
  
  ## Copy the client to the staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    cleanTargetFolder: true

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'my-serviceconnection'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'my-test'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    AppSettings: '-SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT true -WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE 1'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

---

package.json file

```js
{
    "name": "my.site",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "devBuild": "vue-cli-service lint & vue-cli-service build --mode dev",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@okta/okta-vue": "^2.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
        "eslint": "^7.18.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.18.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true,
            "browser": true,
            "es6": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 9,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true,
                "modules": true
            }
        },
        "rules": {
          "keyword-spacing": 2
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: The CSS started working and  I believe it was a capitalization issue but I can't be sure because I changed so many things. The build is completing but I am now getting an issue where I am just seeing the default web app screen  azure  puts up and not my app after a I successful build. That is an issue for another SO post, but I am working with azure rep first.

Comment: Hi, could you share the workaround to this issue here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We should run the vue.js project via the cmd `npm run build` instead of `npm run devBuild`, we could refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-build-ci-cd-for-static-vue-js-app-using-azure-devops-789e0a00e999) to build CI/CD For Static Vue.js App Using Azure DevOps pipeline.

Result:

[image]

Comment: devBuild was actually something I set up to make sure it got dev secrets.